# Java, subtracting double data type

Tags: java, double, subtraction

I am trying to do a simple calculation. I can't figure out how to subtract "double admissionPrice" in the last if-else statements.

Its pointing to the subtraction sign giving me this error message:
operator - cannot be applied to java.lang.String,double

Please help. thanks.

---

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


class IMC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numEmployees = 0;
    double costPerAttendee = 0.00;
    int employeeDiscount;
    double admissionPrice = 0.00;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter amount of employees attending: ");
    numEmployees = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Have any employees attended previously? \n For: YES=1 or NO=2"
                        );
    employeeDiscount = keyboard.nextInt();



    if (numEmployees == 1)  { admissionPrice = 695.00;


    } else if (numEmployees == 2 || numEmployees ==  3 ||numEmployees ==  4) { admissionPrice = 545.00;


    } else if (numEmployees >= 5 ||numEmployees >= 6 ||numEmployees >= 7 ||numEmployees >= 8){ admissionPrice = 480.00;


    }  else if (numEmployees >= 9)  { admissionPrice = 395.00;

    }

        System.out.print("The cost per attendee is: " + admissionPrice );


  if (employeeDiscount == 1){
        System.out.print("Total price after discount (15%) is : " + admissionPrice - (admissionPrice * 0.15) );

    } else if (employeeDiscount == 2) {
            System.out.print("No discount. Total price is still: " + admissionPrice);
    }   


    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `()` around to avoid that `(admissionPrice - (admissionPrice * 0.15))`.

Comment: Try wrapping the whole numerical expression in parentheses: `(admissionPrice - (admissionPrice * 0.15))`

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes here, doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Place parenthesis around `(admissionPrice - (admissionPrice * 0.15) )`. Right now, it concatenates admissionPrice on to `"Total price after discount (15%) is : "` before attempting subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator in your `println()` statement is taking precedence and converting `admissionPrice` to a `String`.

Put your arithmetic operation in parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print("Total price after discount (15%) is : " + (admissionPrice - (admissionPrice * 0.15)));
                                                            ^                                        ^
```

You need to add `()` to fix the precedence, else, as the error indicates, you are subtracting, not from `admissionPrice` but the string that is formed of `"To....:" + admissionPrice`